# Как в Delphi получить результат запроса SQL на выборку из указателя?

Tags: sql, delphi, firedac

Вот запрос `select @someval`. если я раньше делал

`... := FDQuery.FieldByName('someval').AsString`

То теперь пишет что не находит Field "someval"

Пробовал поменять запрос на `select (@someval) as someval` результат пустая строка

Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: добавьте `FROM dual`

Comment: @Akina `select (@someval) as someval FROM dual`?

Comment: Нашел ошибку, Я сохранял в `@someval+name`, а читал из  `@someval`, по поводу `FROM dual`, работает и так и так, что это?